# Find the duplicate IDs if they meet the condition that all the columns are same and create a new column which shows the duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

Consider a dataframe in R, like below. I want to create the column Duplicate_IDs using dplyr library.
Appreciate if anyone can help with the logic to find duplicates using dplyr.

| id | Column A | Column B | Column C | DUPLICATE_IDs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 100 | 100 | ABC | 10 |
| 10 | 100 | 100 | ABC | 8 |
| 17 | 200 | 250 | XYZ | 18,19 |
| 18 | 200 | 250 | XYZ | 17,19 |
| 19 | 200 | 250 | XYZ | 17,18 |
| 20 | 50 | 50 | PQR | NA |

I tried this:

```
data <- data %>% group_by(`Column A`, `Column B`, `Column C`) %>%
              mutate(Duplicate_IDs = ifelse(n() > 1, paste(`ID`, collapse = ","), NA)) %>% ungroup()
```

However I am not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply` in each group.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(DUPLICATE_IDs = sapply(row_number(), \(i) toString(id[-i])),
         .by = c(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC))

#   id ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC DUPLICATE_IDs
# 1  8     100     100     ABC            10
# 2 10     100     100     ABC             8
# 3 17     200     250     XYZ        18, 19
# 4 18     200     250     XYZ        17, 19
# 5 19     200     250     XYZ        17, 18
# 6 20      50      50     PQR
```

---

Before `dplyr v1.1.0`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) %>%
  mutate(DUPLICATE_IDs = sapply(row_number(), \(i) toString(id[-i]))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapply` to loop over ids and rows by groups. `x[-y]` means that you are subsetting from `id`s of the group the `y` row, which is the row number of a given row in the group:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(`Column A`, `Column B`, `Column C`) %>% 
  mutate(DUPLICATE_IDs = mapply(\(x, y) toString(x[-y]), list(unique(id)), seq_along(id)))

#   id Column A Column B Column C DUPLICATE_IDs
# 1  8      100      100      ABC            10
# 2 10      100      100      ABC             8
# 3 17      200      250      XYZ        18, 19
# 4 18      200      250      XYZ        17, 19
# 5 19      200      250      XYZ        17, 18
# 6 20       50       50      PQR
```

Comment: Thank you Maël. Can the solution be a little easier?

Comment: Not sure. Let me explain